# Как присвоить значения hide к cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте . Как присвоить значения hide к cookie . Чтобы при клике значения дива был hide и сохранялся в cookie . Только при перезагрузки браузера показывался див

```
$('#get-started').click(function() {
    var wrapPos = $('.header').offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: wrapPos
    }, 500);
 $('.blockphoto').hide(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Возьми какой-нибудь плагин для jQuery, который работает с куками, например [jquery cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    if ('hidden' == $.cookie('blockphoto_hide')) // прочитать куку
    {
        $('.blockphoto').hide(); // скрыть блок
    } else {
        $('.blockphoto').show(); // показать блок
    }

    $('#get-started').on('click',function(){
        $('.blockphoto').toggle( // переключить видимость блока
           function(){ // после переключения выполнить этот метод
              if (!$(this).is(':visible')) { // если элемент не видно
                  $.cookie('blockphoto_hide', 'hidden'); // ... установить куку "скрыто"
              } else { // иначе
                  $.cookie('blockphoto_hide', ''); // ... удалить куку "скрыто"
              }
           }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но не работает.   $('.???').on('click',function(){
        if (???) { // в  if что надо написать ? 
Я так сделал    var show =  $('.blockphoto').show(); и подставил в if но сработала

Comment: Переписал свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но снова не сработала